# I'm creating a new collection (modified shape) , but the collection created is empty

Tags: mongoose, model, nestjs

**boilerplate**: nestjs-mongoose. => standalone app(console app)
https://docs.nestjs.com/standalone-applications#getting-started

I defined schemas for the database , inject models on the service than a principal function inorder to find all documents in the old models , than transform it with a customized design for this model .
The new database created composed of all documents following the first model , but the documents is empty (created with the (_id & _v )fields ).

i tried following this function : (this function is composed on the service

```js
 async createNewDatabase() {
const countDocuments= await this.databaseModel.countDocuments({});
console.log(`Number of documents in the collection is: ${countDocuments}`);

        const oldModel= await this.databaseModel.find({});
        console.log(`Number of documents retrieved from the oldModel collection: ${databaseModel.length}`);
    
       
        const newCollectionModel= await Promise.all(oldModel.map(async (client: AirBnb) => {
            let newModel = {
                type: client.type,
                properties: client.properties && {
                    city: client.city,
                    city_code: '00000',
                    length: client.properties.longueur,
                    width: client.properties.largeur,
                    postal: '',
                    created: client.properties.dateReleve,
                    updated: client.properties.mtlastEditDateField,
                    geographique_point_2d: client.properties.geoPoint2d,
                    producer: 'liberty SAS',
                 }}};
            const newCollectionCreated = await this.databaseModel.create(newCollectionModel);
            return newCollectionCreated ;
        }));
    }
```

```
the main ts fileis created this way , refering to the service as a standalone app
```